# Creating Monero payment buttons which convert USD to Monero, customers pays and monero sent to my wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-rpc

I have been looking at the developers sections for a solution. Is it possible to create a payment button for Monero similar to Paypal for an e-commerce website and have the monero sent to my GUI Wallet? I suppose I want a very simplied version of Globee. I prefer a solution using PHP and MYSQL on an Apache server which is what the website will be made in. At home I will be using Win 10, and a Monero GUI and running my own node.

Let us suppose that I want customers to click on a button to make a payment for $20.
I would like this converted into Monero using some sort of converter which converts USD to XMR. 
The customer makes the payment. 
Two payment confirmations are sent out by email. One email to me, telling me who (email identity) paid what for which service. And the other email to the customer. 
In these emails, and in the transaction itself there should be some form of unique identity number which only the two of us know, in order to affirm payment. I think this is already included in Monero transactions, but i'd like it to show in the emails so customer gets proof of payment/invoice.

**So with this in mind, my questions are:**

1. Should I be looking at the Monero Integrations Library written in
   PHP? https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp Or is there another tutorial relevant to what I want to do?
2. Would OpenAlias be relevant to me?
3. If I used the ‘subaddress’ facility in Monero to generate an address
   and use that on the website, would that be sufficient to pull out a
   new address for each customer? Should I combine with OpenAlias here?
4. Do I need to make RPC calls to the Monerod Daemon if I have the
   Monerod sent to my wallet direct?
5. As I understand, I would need to set these parameters in the code
   but I’m wondering if I need any others?

   Monero address
   Tx_payment_id
   Recipient _name
   TX_amount
   TX_description
6. By any chance, is there some code around I could just copy and paste
   and use?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Globee works but you can certainly build a payment gateway for monero as you described.

If you're planning to do everything yourself php is a bad programming language for this. Because php is only executed when someone visits a page and is not constantly running so you're going have to run cron jobs that check for new incomming transactions every 2 minutes ( monero's block time ) and it's going to get messy.

On the other hand if you want to get things done as quick as possible check out https://coinpayments.net. They have plugins for popular e-commerce platforms which you can check out at https://www.coinpayments.net/merchant-tools-plugins. They also have REST api if you need. CoinPayments is something I know exists I'm sure you can find other services like this one if this one doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: thank you. I looked on their 'accepted cryptocurrencies' page and Monero is not offered. Do you know what programming lingo they use? I wasn't aware that php was a bad language for this. I don't necessarily want incoming transactions to show 24 hours every 2 minutes.

Comment: @Kesta I just checked and they DO support monero